# problem of path with xml file

Tags: xml, audio

i'd like to import a flash audio player in my wordpress theme, the import of the file works fine because it shows up on screen, responds to the click on play/pause, but the sound does not start.

edit : i found out the path has to be modified in the .as file, with the right path. Thanks sancho

All the files are in : /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/maVersion/

and the mp3 are in :
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/maVersion/audio

i'm in local, so i tried with the whole path (see the first line) or with a "normal" path (like the second line - i made 2 tests for both examples) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PLAYLIST>
<SONG URL="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/maVersion/audio/dance.mp3" TITLE="First Track - Dance" ARTIST="John Doe" />
<SONG URL="audio/audio.mp3" TITLE="Second Track" ARTIST="Random Singer"/>
<SONG URL="audio/dance.mp3" TITLE="Third Track" ARTIST="Super Generic Singer"/>
</PLAYLIST>
```

but still no sound.

Does anybody know what the solution is?

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be putting in the URL rather than a system path as the flash will requesting files via http.

Say your site is on http://localhost/wordpress/ ...

Your URLs need to look like http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/maVersion/audio/dance.mp3

Comment: Thanks sanchothefat! okay i found out i had to change the path in the .as file, i added the rest of the path from the http:// and it works. Thanks a lot ! Cheers man